# WordPress Translations

Tags: translation, localization

I've just recently learned about .po and .mo files in WordPress Themes. My question is, are these files supposed to be used to translate page and post content or just the WordPress backend along with Plugins?

Comment: [This Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) explains how translation functions work.

Comment: Yes, I read through the codex and it seemed to me that the .po files are used to translate text strings in development files. We are in the process of having our sites content translated and the translation service has requested the .po files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.po and .mo files are for translating strings in code files. For translating post content use a translation plugin. I've used a few and find [WPML](http://wpml.org/) to be the best in many aspects.

Incidentally, they have a built-in workflow for translating both content and strings in code files.

Comment: Thank you shahar, the translation service caused me some confusion today. Thanks again!